# Trouble understanding the calling of global variables with in a class to a method within the class

Tags: php, arrays, global-variables

I am having trouble with my numberOfDecks method. I try to call the array of cards that is created in my constructor, but the an error keeps coming up that I am passing an undefined variable ($cards). I thought since it is a global variable $cards would be able to be called to the numberOfDecks method.

```
<?php
/* creating a deck of cards class to be used in a blackJack game*/

class Deck{

  public  $cards = array();

  //creates an instance of a deck of cards (works)

  public function __construct(){
    $values =array('2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','J','Q','K','A');
    $suits =array('Diamond','Club','Heart','Spade');
      foreach ($suits as $suit) {
         foreach($values as $value){
           $this->cards[] = "$value of $suit's";
         }
      }
  }

  /*trying to add more decks to increase number of total cards
  in my array  (does not work)*/

  public function numberOfDecks($number){

    $this->cards = $cards;
    $this->number= $number;
    for($i = 0 ; $i < $number; $i++){
          array_push($cards[],$i);
    }
    return $cards;

  }
}



$deck = new Deck();//works as expected
$deck->numberOfDecks(3);//trouble 
$shuffled = shuffle($deck->cards);//works as expected
var_dump($deck);
```

Comment: this is basiclly a dupe of your last question

Comment: @Dagon How so they are the same program but it is a different question completely and if you don't want to look at my questions by all means just move along

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable `$cards` is undefined because you don't declare it.

```
public function numberOfDecks($number){

$this->cards = $cards;
```

You probably meant to flip the assignment direction.

```
$cards = $this->cards;
```

Given your comment for adding decks to the object total deck, after flipping the assignment direction, try using [`array_merge`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)

[Here's a working fiddle.](https://3v4l.org/h3Sv5)

```
<?php

class Deck{

  public  $cards = array();

  //creates an instance of a deck of cards (works)

  public function __construct(){
    $values =array('2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','J','Q','K','A');
    $suits =array('Diamond','Club','Heart','Spade');
      foreach ($suits as $suit) {
         foreach($values as $value){
           $this->cards[] = "$value of $suit's";
         }
      }
  }

    public function numberOfDecks($number){

        $cards = $this->cards;

        $this->number = $number;
        for($i = 0 ; $i < $number; $i++){
            $this->cards = array_merge($this->cards, $cards);
        }

    }
}



$deck = new Deck();//works as expected

// how many cards are intially constructed?
echo "count of cards in new deck: " . count($deck->cards) . "\n<br/>\n";

// add 3 more decks of cards
$deck->numberOfDecks(3);//trouble 
echo "count of cards after adding 3 decks: " . count($deck->cards);

// $shuffled = shuffle($deck->cards);//works as expected
// var_dump($deck);
```

Results in this output:

> count of cards in new deck: 52
>   
>   count of cards after adding 3 decks: 208

Comment: I am still having trouble with the addition of multiple decks I have tried the array_push and the array_merge functions and I am still having troubles

Comment: I am still having trouble with adding more cards to the overall deck I have tried array_merge and array_push and they both failed

Comment: @watkins1179 I've updated my answer to [demonstrate the full example](https://3v4l.org/h3Sv5). I hope it helps.

Comment: @Jeff_Puckett_II Thank you I had made a mistake in my implementation of your example the method works as expected now thank you

Comment: @watkins1179 no problem, happy to help!